# React 'npm start' giving me errors, for other projects the command executes successfully

Tags: reactjs

$ npm start

> coin-flipper@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Student\Desktop\React\Exercises
> react-scripts start

Invalid options object. React Refresh Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options.overlay.module: The provided value "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\React JS\Exercises!\draw\node_modules\react-dev-utils\refreshOverlayInterop.js" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! coin-flipper@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the coin-flipper@0.1.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

i have tried deleting package-lock and node_modules and running npm install, still gives the same error, however the other project executes successfully and i did a comparison of the .json files of both files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your path contains an exclamation point. `Exercises!` is triggering this. Rename the folder to `Exercises` and it should be solved.